# Is there a way to select a file in Windows and get its file path with one shortcut?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there some application for selecting a file in Windows Explorer, and copy its file path to the clipboard, with one shortcut?

Does Windows have some built-in tool for it?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's built in to Windows...

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right-Click the file -> `Copy As Path`

More Info: [Get the Full Path of a Folder or File in Windows 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff678296.aspx)

Additionally here's a page that explains how to add custom entries to show on the non-Shifted context menu:

[Copy File Path And Name Using Windows Explorer Context Menu Extensions](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=168&t=Copy_File_Path_and_Name_using_Windows_Explorer_Context_Menu_Extensions)

Comment: Why shift? Right click do the same for me. And I don't have "copy as path" in the list of actions.

Comment: Okay, my bad. It works, just hidden in the 20 possible actions in my computer!

Comment: @Vadorequest Doing Shift + Right-Click in Windows sometimes gives alternate or additional menu items. For instance, Shift + R-clicking in an Explorer window will give the option to open a Command Prompt window with the current working directory set to the folder currently displayed in Explorer when you select said menu option.

Comment: Using Window for almost 15 years and don't know such thing... Feel bad.

Comment: @Vadorequest Don't feel too bad; it was new to Vista.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If you're using Windows' built-in explorer (not Internet Explorer), you can hold down the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key and press right click on the item (which can be a file or folder). Then the only thing you need to do is select the "Copy as path" option. Now the path of the item will be placed in your clipboard and you can use it by pasting it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Path Copy Copy](http://pathcopycopy.codeplex.com/) for that which supports various paths including UNC, Internet style, Unix, Cygwin and so on. Its context menu is fully configurable so you can leave your favourites there. "Long Path" and "UNC Path" are my favourites.

Answer (score 1):

For the moment I've found [Copy path](http://copypath.codeplex.com/) for Windows that:

> that will allow you to right click on a drive or file system object
>   and copy the path of the file to the clipbpoard. If the drive is a
>   mapped drive or the file system object exits on a mapped drive it will
>   resolve the full UNC path..